# JPA - How to populate a DTO using criteriaBuilder.construct from an Entity Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have these (minimal and partial) JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    protected Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
...
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee implements Serializable {
    private BigDecimal salary;
    ...
}

@Entity
...
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee implements Serializable {
   private BigDecimal hourlyWage;
   private BigDecimal maxHoursWeek;
    ...
}
```

Currently we are using spring-data-jpa to query, like this:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    List<Employee> findAll();
}
```

But, this way we have 'N+1' problems and lot of selects, so, i decide to use Criteria API and select it into a DTO, like this:

```
public List<EmployeeDTO> findAll() {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EmployeeDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EmployeeDTO.class);

    Root<Employee> root = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
    Root<FullTimeEmployee> fullTimeEmployeeRoot = criteriaBuilder.treat(root, FullTimeEmployee.class);
    Root<PartTimeEmployee> partTimeEmployeeRoot = criteriaBuilder.treat(root, PartTimeEmployee.class);

    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(EmployeeDTO.class,
                          root.get("id"), root.get("name"), 
                          fullTimeEmployeeRoot.get("salary"), 
                          partTimeEmployeeRoot.get("hourlyWage"))
    );

    return this.entityManager
            .createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

And this is our (example) DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal fullTimeEmployeeSalary;
    private BigDecimal partTimeEmployeeHourlyWage;
    private BigDecimal partTimeEmployeeMaxHoursWeek;
    ...
}
```

But, we got 0 results.

Our hibernate output looks like this:

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.name, fullTimeEmployee.salary, partTimeEmployee.hourlyWage partTimeEmployee.maxHoursWeek ... FROM employees employee INNER JOIN fullTimeEmployees fullTimeEmployee on fullTimeEmployee.id = employee.id INNER JOIN partTimeEmployees partTimeEmployee on partTimeEmployee.id = employee.id
```

My question is: What is the best way to do that? How i transform these INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs? Exists a better way?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, trying to do that is losing information. Why not just `employeeRepository.findAll()`? This will give you a list with mixed FTEs and PTEs and you will go through the list and invoke a method depending on instance type. What you want gives you a null in one or the other field that's just ugly because you will have to check for nulls all the time. Even better you could probably have each concrete class implement an interface and so not even have to check which type is in the list. Even better yet use the decorator pattern.

Comment: The answer is simple, thus you still have to query and retrieve every single fields on each entities just to compute a wage amount, where it could be done directly by the query. As you asked it originally, you can change JOIN type with CriteriaAPI by using the .join() second parameter : `.join("yourField", JoinType.LEFT)`.

Answer (score 1):

First let me say thank you for the very nicely formatted question -- you did a great job of making a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think you want to project the result into such a class as you describe. Having a class with either a `salary` or `hourlyWage` value means you have keep checking for null all the time and that's a pretty bad design decision. Better is to get the list of different types from the `employeeRepository` and use object oriented principles to handle the mixed types. This is exactly what OOP was invented for.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    public abstract BigDecimal getPay();

@Entity
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private int daysWorked;
    @Override
    public BigDecimal getPay() {
        return salary
                .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(daysWorked))
                .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(Year.now().length()), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    }

@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    private BigDecimal hourlyWage;
    private int hoursWorked;
    @Override
    public BigDecimal getPay() {
        return hourlyWage.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(hoursWorked));
    }
```

and then

```
BigDecimal sum = employeeRepo.findAll()
                     .stream()
                     .map(e->e.getPay())
                     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Hi, K.Nicholas, thanks for your help! It is a good solution... But, what happens if i'll need another attribute,
which only exists in one of the entities, for example: maxHoursWeek? Are i'll need create all these abstracts methods?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is always a good question. Personally I would think in terms of separating processing for hourly and salary employees. You just get a list of salary employees from a `FullTimeEmployeeRepository` and a separate list of hourly employees from a `PartTimeEmployeeRepository` and process the two lists separately. There are enough differences that in the real world it would be insane to mix them up, at least for processing. It might not be unreasonable to have the inheritance in the database like this but it would be rare to retrieve only employees.

Comment: PS> "But, what happens if i'll need another attribute, which only exists in one of the entities, for example: maxHoursWeek?" -> that's effectively what the decorator pattern was invented to address.

Comment: K.Nicholas, thank you again for your help, sorry i cannot upvote your answer, i do not have reputation yet.